# ios 7 uitableviewcell drawing changes

Tags: uitableview, drawing, ios7, heightforrowatindexpath

I have an issue on iOS 7 with a custom cell drawing (on iOS 6 and 5 is working fine).

On heightForRowAtIndexPath I'm returning a smaller height than the real height of the cell for the last row of each section, because I need the last cell to overlap with the header of the next section.

It seems that Apple made a drawing improvement or something on iOS 7 because only the height returning from heightForRowAtIndexPath is drawing so my cell will be cut at the bottom.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm here is what I would do...

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == [_array_todo count]) {
        // last row
        return 50;
    }else{
        // not the last row
        return 80;
    }
}
```

Also consider what you are doing when cell is selected....

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    sel_path = indexPath;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: I did the same in heightForRowAtIndexPath before iOS 7, but on iOS 7 is not working correctly. If you return 50 for the last row, only 50 px height will be draw, so the bottom of the cell won't be displayed.

Comment: Have you tried to subclass the Cell and use the -(bool)setSelected method ? you can hide when cell is not selected and show again when the cell is selected...

Comment: Like I said previously, I already have a custom cell and the cell is not selectable, you cannot tap on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and situation(tapping last cell with lower height to add more data). I didn't research why that happens, but something worked for me. I used data for table from NSDictionary. It worked perfectly for iOS6.1 and earlier. In iOS7 it led to same bug as yours. Allocating data into separate NSMutableArray in viewDidLoad solved it. So instead of using everywhere in tableview delegate methods

```
[self.data objectForKey:@"offers"]
```

I did

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (!tableData) tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.data objectForKey:@"offers"]];
}
```

And replaced all. Hope that helps for you too.